# MarketingCloud get a list of MobileConnect messages using REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect

Does anyone know how to get a list of MobileConnect messages returned using REST API? When you go to MobileConnect in SFMC web app, there is a list of messages, I want to retrieve text content for each message.

I am following this [guide](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html), but under /sms/v1 there is no method support this requirement.